# I didn't get listener file get installed

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle-sql-developer

I have downloaded oracle sql developer to access Remote database. After downloading i couldn't connect to the database. I don't have tns.ora file installed in my system neither do i have oracle_home. Do I need to install oracle database too in order to have tns.ora file in my system.

Comment: You don't need `tnsnames.ora` or an `oracle_home` to connect to a remote server. What exactly is the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer can connect to Oracle databases without Oracle client and tnsnames.ora.

[Creating a Database Connection Using SQL Developer](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-0DE0C9F4-8800-4142-A755-14B2FAA6624F.htm#ADMQS12420)

[image]

More details you can read at the above url.